# Creating a window always focused for Windows

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am using Java to create an foreground application that uses the Robot class to send mouse clicks to other applications real-time.

Here's my issue at the moment: my application needs to read from a device in real time and keep sending Robot commands. However, mouse clicks cause the focus to be shifted to other applications. Therefore, I cannot continue reading or sending commands.

I've tried jDialog's and jFrame's `setAutoRequestFocus(false) and true` but I couldn't keep the window's focus.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You will have to use native code

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: You must write keyboard and (if needed) mouse hook as well to caputer input regardless if the apliaction has focus or not. You will be able to send emulate keyboard and mouse input as well. Check some information on JNI and WinAPI (for windows)